# How to block trafic from anonymous proxy to my site?

Tags: nginx, proxy, haproxy, scam

some scammers are trying to reach my site using anonymous proxy.

Is there a way to block connexions from anonymous proxy with haproxy or nginx?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to block all anonymous proxies or just that one?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)

Comment: Want to block ALL anonymous proxy :). Cheers